# Httpsurlconnection doesn't close the socket

Tags: java, android

I have tried to fix this problem but i didn't get a good solution for this.
I just opened a socket with httsurlconnection and closed.
However, the socket i opened didn't close and the socket state was CLOSE_WAIT.
Here is my code and air log for this.
What is wrong with my code?

```
    String https_url = "https://www.google.com";

    URL url = new URL(https_url);

    try {
        con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
        if(con!=null){
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String input = br.readLine();
            while(input.length() != 0)
            {

                input = br.readLine();  
            }
            br.close();
            con.disconnect();               

        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must surly be getting a NullPointerException from this code. You must test the result of readLine() for null before doing anything else. I don't see what the point of testing for an *empty* line in an HTML page is.

Comment: Thank for your advice. :) While I tested this code there were no exception though. You're right. I will add some codes for checking null exception. The purpose of this code is to use httpsurlconnection function to connect over ssl.